# Node Webkit shows uncaught nodejs error when using angularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, node-webkit, angularjs-module

I have been building and debugging an Angular.JS application for several months now running from a browser without any issues whatsoever, however I am now in the stages of packaging it to run in node wrapper. When i created my package.json and ran the folder from nw.exe I get an error that says:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

    ReferenceError: angular is not defined
        at file:///C:/wamp/www/Maintenence/ng/ng-init.js:2:11
```

now the code line it has a problem with in ng-init.js is

```
var app = angular.module('MaintenenceApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

It doesnt like `angular` in `angular.module` and once I received this error I went to the angular.js docs to make sure i hadnt done something wrong here and according to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module this code is 100% correct.

what could be causing this error. as i mentioned, it runs perfectly in a web browser with no errors in js console.

package.json

```
{
    "main": "index.html", 
    "name": "Maintenence Manager", 
    "version": "0.0.1", 
    "window": {
        "toolbar": false,
        "frame"  : true
    }
}
```

here is the order of my scripts in the head of index.html index.html

```
<didnt seem important to show css links and such but jquery is also in the page>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
<Script type="text/javascript" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/angular-route.js"></Script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ng/ng-init.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Node Webkit doesn't support `src="//url.com"` which i use so the http/https thing doesn't become in issue.

Replacing the urls for the scripts with `src="http://url.com"` fixed my issue.